# Android: disable (or change of the function of ) the return key when AutoCompleteTextView is focused

Tags: android, return

My app has an AutoCompleteTextView used for searching. When it's in focus, I would like to disable or change the function of the return key to a specific function call. I tried in my layout xml to add the following property to the AutoCompleteTextView

```
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

But it works on my simulator (when you click enter, the keyboard disappears) but it doesn't work on my device (moto droidx running 2.3.3).

Can someone show me how I can link the return key to a specific function (in my case, the search function) with android:imeOptions="actionGo"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Write your code in `setOnEditorActionListener` event of `EditText` family. like

```
autoEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                    KeyEvent event) {
                if (event != null&& (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                   // in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(autoEditText.getApplicationWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                   //Commented line is for hide keyboard. Just make above code as comment and test your requirement
                   //It will work for your need. I just putted that line for your understanding only
                   //You can use own requirement here also.
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

For me it works if you add one more line about input type:

```
android:inputType="text"
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```